# When I try to run a Post User Registration script in Auth0 it gives "Error! API Error. Please contact support if the problem persists" error

Tags: node.js, auth0

I am trying to use Auth0's actions for post user registration. When I try to test it via UI, it gives me an error like "Error! API Error. Please contact support if the problem persists" and in the console it only writes "Error: {}". The script I wrote for this action looks something like this:

```
const https = require('https');
const jsonwebtoken = require('jsonwebtoken');

/**
 * @param {Event} event - Details about registration event.
 */
exports.onExecutePostUserRegistration = async (event) => {
    const TOKEN_SIGNING_KEY = event.secrets.signingKey
    const TOKEN_EXPIRATION_IN_SECONDS = 10

    const payload = {
        email: event.user.email,
        name: event.user.given_name,
        surname: event.user.family_name
    };

    const token = jsonwebtoken.sign(payload, TOKEN_SIGNING_KEY,
        {   subject: "postUserRegistration",
            expiresIn: TOKEN_EXPIRATION_IN_SECONDS });

    console.log("Starting post user registration operations for user with email: ", payload.email);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const request = https.request(url, options,
            (res) => {
                if (res.statusCode === 200) {
                    resolve({statusCode: res.statusCode, headers: res.headers})
                } else {
                    reject({
                        headers: res.headers,
                        statusCode: res.statusCode
                    })
                }
                res.on('error', reject);
            });
        request.on("error", function (e) {
            console.error(e);
            reject({message: {e}});
        });
        request.on("timeout", function () {
            reject({message: "request timeout"});
        })
        request.end();
    });
}
```

Can you help me about what exactly causes this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to understand this problem I tried to assign the Promise to a variable and then see what it returned. The funny part was that it was "pending". It couldn't be "pending" in any way, because it everything was true it would be "resolved", else "rejected" and if there is a timeout/error from the request it would be "rejected".

It turns out that Auth0 has some limitations for [actions](https://auth0.com/docs/customize/actions/limitations) and the endpoint called was stuck to our firewall which caused a timeout in Auth0 before an HTTPS timeout. As the request was broken halfway, it stayed as "pending".